# XPath получение родительского элемента по дочернему элементу

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

```
<div id='1H62FE09A'>
 <div class='MyClassName0'></div>
 <div class='MyClassName1'>MyText</div>
</div>
```

Мне нужно получить родительский эелемнт, id генериться каждый раз заново, так что по нему искать не вариант. Я знаю как получить дочерний элемент:

```
browser.find_by_xpath("//div[@class='MyClassName1' and text()='MyText']")
```

Вопрос: как получить родительский элемент зная дочерний элемент средствами XPath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
//div[./div[@class='MyClassName1' and text()='MyText']]
```

---

Еще, я думаю `find_by_xpath` возвращает объект, у которого можно будет вызвать метод получения родителя

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно!

Да, безусловно, у WebElement селениума есть возможность получить родительский элемент, но мне интересно именно методами XPath.

Answer (score 2):

Ну можно еще таким способом:

```
.//div[@class="MyClassName1" and text()="MyText"]/..
```

Или таким:

```
.//div[@class="MyClassName1" and text()="MyText"]/parent::div
```

Или даже таким:

```
.//div[@class="MyClassName1" and text()="MyText"]/ancestor::div[1]
```